# How can I change for loop according to the condition

Tags: for-loop

I want to change the iteration statement and condition within for loop as below.

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

Here **n** is value which is entered by user. According to "n" value iteration statement should be change.

if n=10 --> i will increase by 1
if n = 100 --> i will increase by 10

But there is no limitation for n value. Is there is way to achieve this?

Comment: how are you defining increments? Are you increasing the increments value at certain *n* values? or is it changing the increments value in every incremental step?

Comment: @Makdous I want to increase increments value at certain n. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: ok so at this certain *n* value do you increase it by ten times the previous value like the example above?

Comment: @Makdous yes it is same as example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //get n value
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i += (int) (0.1 * n)) {
            //loop code
        }
    }
}
```

---

For **example** let's say the user enters *n = 10000* 
The first loop **i = 0** so the increment will be:
**i = 0 + (int) (0.1 * 10000)** 
*i = 1000*

---

The second loop i = 1000 so the increment will be:
**i = 1000 + (int) (0.1 * 10000)**
*i = 2000*
and so on...

The code will work as long as the user enters *n* value that's divided by 10 with 0 remainder.